# Is there an Ubuntu One client for Kubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-one, kubuntu

Is there a UbuntuOne client for Kubuntu or how do I make UbuntuOne work in Kubuntu?

Answer (score 10):

## 12.04

From Precise, there is now an officially supported QT version of the Ubuntu-One client.

[image]

**how to install**

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-control-panel-qt
```

Answer (score 1):

After the installation the QT Ubuntu One client, you have to make a startup item for Ubuntu One\ when your system starts adding the following command:

```
ubuntuone-control-panel-qt --with-icon
```

You can do this clicking at the kickstart icon (down left at your monitor), and type `start` for searching where the application is, to configure the startup apps of your system.

Answer (score 0):

## Install Ubuntu One

### [Option 1] Install Ubuntu One from the command line:

1. Open Konsole and enter the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-control-panel-qt
   ```
2. Enter your password at the password prompt if requested. It should look like this:

   `[sudo] password for user:` where user is your login name. It does not show any echo characters when you type your password.
3. It may prompt you with a question like this: `Do you want to continue [Y/n]?` The capitalized option in brackets is the default choice, so you can just hit enter, type `y` and enter, or `n` if you changed your mind.

### [Option 2] Install Ubuntu one using Muon Software Center

1. Open Muon Software Center from your application launcher.
2. Type *ubuntuone-control-panel-qt* in the search box in the upper right corner.
3. Click on Ubuntu One. Two buttons should appear; click on the one that says Install.

## Make Ubuntu One start when KDE starts

1. Open your KDE autostart folder in Dolphin. It should be `~/.kde/Autostart` (which is short for `/home/user/.kde/Autostart`) unless you moved it.
2. Open Kate and past the following into a blank document:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   Name=Ubuntu One Control Panel
   GenericName=File Synchronizer
   Comment=Sync your files across computers and to the web
   Exec=ubuntuone-control-panel-qt --minimized
   Icon=ubuntuone
   Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
   StartupNotify=false
   OnlyShowIn=KDE;
   ```

   See the [man page](http://www.manpager.com/linux/man1/ubuntuone-control-panel-qt.1.html) and a command explanation

   *Running* `ubuntuone-control-panel-qt --with-icon` *will start the Ubuntu One in the system tray, but it will also open a window. Instead, run* `ubuntuone-control-panel-qt --minimized` at KDE start to start the system tray.*
3. Click File > Save as... and browse to your autostart folder. In the Name: box enter ubuntuone.desktop. See more about [Desktop File Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.0.html) and the file name

   **The file name should end with** `.desktop` **and should not have spaces.**
4. Go to Dolphin that you opened earlier and right-click on the file you just created and select Properties.
5. Under "Properties for ubuntuone.desktop — Dolphin" click on the Permissions tab.
6. Under "Access Permissions" look for "Is executable" and click on the check box if it is empty and click Okay.

---