# U1 client for KDE

Tags: ubuntu-one, kde, client

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an Ubuntu One client for Kubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37105/is-there-an-ubuntu-one-client-for-kubuntu)

Is there U1 client available for KDE? Just signed up for U1 to sync with my android phone, but can't find a client for KDE desktop environment. If not available I'll have to unsubribe and switch to Drobbox or something similar.