# Why isnt there a KDE client for ubuntu one

Tags: ubuntu-one, 11.10, kubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [U1 client for KDE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48074/u1-client-for-kde)

Why isnt there  KDE client? There is windows client but none for KDE.
I am kubuntu user and would like to use the service.

Comment: See this bug: https://launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client-kde

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One for KDE is Alpha Software, which if you would like to test, then proceed otherwise stop right there and install the **GTK Version.**

To install UbuntuOne Alpha 1:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apachelogger/ubuntuone-kde
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-kde
```

---

Note that This was released around 10.10 times so... again this is (outdated) alpha  software.

**Known issue**: in case the "ubuntuone-client-gnome" package is installed, make sure you remove it before installing "ubuntuone-kde".

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/08/install-ubuntuone-alpha-1-for-kde-in.html).