# UbuntuOne on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an Ubuntu One client for Kubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37105/is-there-an-ubuntu-one-client-for-kubuntu)

Is there support for KDE?  I want to install U1 on my Kubuntu computers and get rid of Dropbox but I cannot until it has Dolphin support.  Thanks.

Kubuntu 11.10 x64

Comment: do you have ubuntu software center in kubuntu

Answer (score 0):

you can download ubuntuone from software center 
           or
type in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apachelogger/ubuntuone-kde

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-kde
```

and

you can download any other file manager rather than dolphin

you can use `exo-utils` or `pcmanfm` or `thunar` file manager

install them from software center